# Access protected JSON content from S3 bucket with Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get

How can I access to a protected JSON stored in S3 bucket with Swift?

My credentials are an AccessKey and a SecurityKey.

I configure:

```
let jsonUrlS3 = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/2018/August/json_name.json"
let url = URL(string: jsonUrlS3)

let accessKey = "xxxxxxxxxx"
let secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxx"

let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

But how can I tell the code "Ok, I'm in. Now access to the url"?

Comment: What tutorial did you follow for download? Maybe look at the documentation of the client you are using.

Comment: There's no "I'm in" with IAM credentials. You have them, or you don't. There's no login. If you have them, then you can make API calls.